# Is it possible context menu item to be disabled in firefox add-on SDK?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

Is there a way of item context-menu to be inactive, that is, to prevent interaction with the mouse? I look at the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/context-menu) for the context-menu, but I did not see anything about it.

I have developing a application that handle selected text from user when 
user choose one item from the context menu. Very similar with this [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Add_a_Context_Menu_Item).

I want under certain conditions, context-menu item to be inactive. If may be slightly gray or different kind of will be much better.

Comment: For all websites or for specific webpage ?

Comment: The question is edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [specifying a context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/context-menu#Specifying_Contexts) for which the context-menu item should be displayed you can hide the menuitem (ie not display the menuitem).

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/context-menu#Specifying_Contexts

If you want to have the context-menu displayed and disabled, then this is not currently supported, and you can [file a bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?product=Add-on%20SDK) describing your use case.  I think support for a "disabled" state would make sense.